# "Negative dimension size" using keras

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123) #for reproducibility

from keras.models import sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,28,28)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
```

Here's the error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_6/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 3, 3, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_6/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,28,28], [3,3,28,32].
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Hey Tuba Umer! please try to give a better title to this question to allow readers to better understand if they could help you solve the issue, and also to allow future users to find the questions when they face similar issues.

It would also be helpful to present the general thing you are trying to achieve in the code before pasting the (quite long) code.

good luck!

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the title to better describe the individual error (which it previously didn't say anything about at all), but you could probably do better in editing it further yourself. Having a specific title is important for helping others to find an error -- nobody is going to click on a search link for "I'm getting this error in my code" if they don't know that "this error" is the same error they're trying to solve themselves.

Comment: Sure. I'm new at this but thanks for your help. I will be careful next time.

Comment: Can you please add the error's stacktrace, it might make locating the error easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in input shape should be the batch size, obviously if your input shape is (1,28,28) the 3 x 3 kernel can not be used because 1-3 is negative, so change your input shape to (28,28,1) or (None,28,28,1) both in your model and your dataset.

The input size of model should be (batch,width,height,channel)

Comment: Thank you. But I am also getting an error on nb_epoch. This is the error: TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nb_epoch'. Please help.

Comment: according to this issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14135 nb_epoch is deprectaed, use epoch instead

Comment: I did it's still show a very big error.

Comment: ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-6d6fa0052189> in <module>()
     37 
     38 model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
39           batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1)
9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise
ValueError: in user code:

Comment: Can you please print x_train.shape after you reshape it ? I think it is because the shape of your dataset and your input shape does not match

Comment: I just did it's not working. It's related to the epochs now.